# using ACPI in terminal

Tags: ssh, centos, acpi

I'm running Centos on my home laptop just to play around with, I ACPID running which is letting g-p-m get the battery information but I want to find out battery information over ssh and acpi doesn't work.

I've tried to locate it but no such success. Where is it or what am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you want to know about the battery? Can't it be done by reading files from /proc/acpi/battery?

Personally, I'm having 2 battery's for my laptop: a new/good one and a battery that I broke by having the laptop hooked up to the adapter almost 24/7. When I'm visiting a customer, I remove the old battery and hook up the new one. But sometimes, when I get back to my office, I forget to put back the old battery.

So what I did: I wrote a cron script that reads the serial number from /proc/acpi/battery/C1F4/info to see what battery is connected. And if it's the wrong one, a passive popup (kdialog) is shown.

Comment: I don't use it as a laptop, its use it as a server that has a built in UPS :), Although I would prefer to get it from using acpi checking that file is sufficient. Cheers.